# How to calculate AUC for random forest model in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, auc

The label in my data is a (N by 1) vector. The label values are either 0 for negative samples or 1 for positive samples (so, it's a binary classification problem). I use the `.fit` function of sklearn and fitted a random forest on my train set. To calculate AUC for the test set I use `metrics.roc_auc_score (test_labels, probabilities)`. I'm using 
`predict_proba(my_test_set)` to get the probabilities. However, `predict_proba(my_test_set)` returns a (N_test, 2) matrix. I saw many people use the second column of this returned matrix (`predict_proba(my_test_set)[:,1]`) and feed it to the `metrics.roc_auc_score` to calculate AUC, but why the second one? Why not the first column (`predict_proba(my_test_set)[:,0]`)?

Answer (score 10):

ROC AUC is calculated by comparing the true label vector with the probability prediction vector of the **positive** class.

All `scikit-learn` classifiers, including `RandomForestClassifier`, will set the class with the highest label to be the positive class, and the corresponding predicted probabilities will always be in the second column of the `predict_proba` matrix. `roc_auc_score` does the same assumption and also assumes the class with the highest label to be the positive class. Hence, both have the same definition of what the positive class is and `roc_auc_score` expects the classifier to have put the corresponding probabilities in the second column beforehand.

This is why you should always do:

```
roc_auc_score(y_test, RFC.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer! Then, what is in the first column (```predict_proba(my_test_set)[:,0]```)? Probabilities of the negative class? Is that why ```predict_proba(my_test_set)[i,0] + predict_proba(my_test_set)[i,1] = 1```? Thanks!

Comment: @khemedi exactly!

Answer (score 2):

[**`roc_auc_score()`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) would expect the `y_true` be a binary indicator for the class and `y_score` be the corresponding scores.

As in your case, `y_true` is the binary indicator for positive class. For understanding, which column represent the probability score of which class, use `clf.classes_`. In our examples, it would return `array([0,1])`. Hence, we need to use the second column, to get the probability scores for class 1.

Even when you have multi-class problem, convert your labels (`y`) into binary indicator for the required class and the pick the corresponding column from the output of `predict_proba()` using `clf.classes_`.

Look at [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py) example for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it does return [0, 1]

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn has a [*ROC Curve with Visualization API*](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator) which can be applied to random forest as well, and supplies among other things the AUC score. Here is the part of their code relevant to the random forest:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_wine(return_X_y=True)
y = y == 2

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
ax = plt.gca()
rfc_disp = RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(rfc, X_test, y_test, ax=ax, alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

with the result
[image]